# Object's keys and values shown correctly by console log but undefined when trying to access

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I fetch orders and workers data from 2 different APIs.
Orders API got workerId and workers API got workerId as well, so I need to kind of bind it together and showing each card having order and worker information.

eg., Order 1 - Tom, Order 3 - Jack...

I set a state which is an array containing objects and each object eventually got both orders and workers infomarion together

eg.,

```
 {
    "order" : 1,
    "workerName" : "Tom",
      .
      .
      .
  }
```

By console.log, it looks fine showing keys and values with no problem but trying to access worker data, I got undefined unlike order data.

My code below:

```
const [workData, setWorkData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
   let works = []
   fetchOrders().then(res => {
     res.forEach(work => {
       fetchWorkers(work.workerId).then(res => {
         work.companyName = res.companyName
         work.email = res.email
         work.image = res.image
         work.workerName = res.name
       })
       works.push(work)
     })
     setWorkData(works)
   })
 }, [])

              .
              .
              .

 {workData.map(work => {
        console.log(work) // shows fine all keys values
        console.log(work.deadline) // accessible
        console.log(work.companyName) // undefined
        return (
          <Grid.Column key={work.id} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
            <WorkCard 
              companyName={work.companyName}
              deadline={work.deadline}
              description={work.description}
              email={work.email}
              id={work.id}
              image={work.image}
              name={work.name}
              workerName={work.workerName}
            />
          </Grid.Column>
        )
      })}
```

Comment: i guess workdata is getting async called so, initially it would be blank [] and later on it will add data, but loop will still execute even it is blank array and thats why maybe you are not getting data if you could  show an working example then better could we help

Comment: That looks like you're running multiple asynchronous requests. Use `Promise.all()` for that. `map()` the elements of the orders array to a fetch Promise each, then pass that to `Promise.all()`

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/fYjUmQ5g

Comment: @Chris G, the link code works, I really appreciate so like you mentioned I used async requests like fetchOrders and fetchWorkers. If it is more than one it has to be Promise.all?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but if you want to wait until all results are in, then yes, Promise.all() is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not await the execution but set the empty data directly.

Try something like this:

```
useEffect(async () => {
   let works = []
   const orders = await fetchOrders();
   await Promise.all(orders.map(async work => {
       const worker = await fetchWorkers(work.workerId);
       work.companyName = res.companyName
       work.email = res.email
       work.image = res.image
       work.workerName = res.name
       })
       works.push(work)
     })
     setWorkData(works)
   })
 }, []);
```

This will await each execution and set the data after that. Right now you are setting the data directly before the fetches are executed.

Comment: @Domono987, Directly put async on useEffect is warning me tough, solved it using Promise.all. Thank you for your solution.